# Remove console.logs using Parcel?

Tags: parceljs

Trying to remove `console.log` statements using Parcel.

Here's `package.json`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "select2": "^4.0.6-rc.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cssnano": "^4.1.9",
    "parcel-plugin-web-extension": "^1.5.1"
  }
}
```

The [Parcel docs on transformations](https://parceljs.org/transforms.html) says:

> Parcel automatically runs these transforms when it finds a configuration file (e.g. .babelrc, .postcssrc) in a module.

I've added this `.uglifyrc` to my project root:

```
{
  "compress": {
    "pure_funcs": ["console.log"]
  }
}
```

But when I run `parcel build src/index.js` none of the console.log statements are removed from the `dist/index.js`.

Think I'm missing something obvious here.  Thanks!

**Edit**: looks like [Parcel supported Uglify](https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/pull/287) at some point and may still, though [per @MTCoster's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54680081/remove-console-logs-using-parcel#comment96149088_54680081) the docs don't indicate that it does.

So I replaced my `.uglifyrc` file with this `.babelrc` file and `console.log` calls are now gone:

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-remove-console"]
}
```

Comment: From the linked page: “*You can transform JavaScript using Babel, CSS using PostCSS, and HTML using PostHTML.*” - Nothing in there about uglify

Comment: Interesting, good catch.  I found the Uglifier stuff in old Parcel GH Issues.  Maybe they dropped support.  Will try Babel.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parcel doesn't have documented support of Uglifier.  Use Babel instead:

Replace `.uglifyrc` file with this `.babelrc` file and `console.log` calls are now gone:

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-remove-console"]
}
```

Comment: Does this mean you cannot do it with Parcel js at all?

Comment: How to still have console for development, only remove for production build?